# What is the course of inter auricular line?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-ear

**BACKGROUND:** The interauricular line is the line connecting two auricles.

---

I wish to know the exact route through which this line passes. I want to be sure whether it passes through the parietal prominences, or in front of them.

Comment: Could anyone create a tag for cephalometry?

Comment: @JM97 Please do not create new tags for every single possibility. This tag is relatively pointless at the moment and will most likely be orphaned.

Comment: Do you mean the interaural line? If so it is ventral, rather than in front, of most of the parietal bones. This seems like a really odd question - you are using fairly outdated/underused terminology, and the answer is pretty clear if you know what landmarks you are talking about it and just have a look at a skull.

Comment: No I didn't mean interaural line. The terminology is used in my textbook but it doesn't say anymore about its course, so I wondered what could it be.

Comment: Please state the source of your background in the question. That way people trying to answer your question can [possibly] look up your information.

Comment: I found very little use of the term interauricular line in a web search (only about 800 results in Google), and those that gave some sort of definition suggest that it is indeed the same thing as the interaural line. The auricles in this case are a sort of outdated term for the external ears. The interaural line isn't a real thing, it is just a reference point that refers to an imaginary line between the openings of the ear canal. The interauricular line is the same thing but is poorly named, because it is still referring to a line between ear canals, not really the auricles themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up front - I have never heard of this term and I could not find information on the interauricular line. The only thing I was able to dig up was the term ***auricular line***, which is (Fig. 1):

> [The] [l]ine pass[ing] perpendicular to the anthropological baseline,
>   through the cent[er] of the external auditory meatus.

[image: auricular line]
<sup>Fig. 1. Auricular line. source: [Radiology Key](http://radiologykey.com/the-skull/)</sup>

The *anthropological line* being (Fig. 2):

> [The] [l]ine join[ing] the infraorbital margin to the superior border
>   of the external auditory meatus.

[image: anthropological line]
<sup>Fig. 2. Anthropological line. source: [Radiology Key](http://radiologykey.com/the-skull/)</sup>